# Eclipse RCP | How to get current View from Widget side?

Tags: view, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Widget for Eclipse RCP. I made a Shell, which I want to combine with Events (Resize, Move etc.) in a View, in which I have a Composite. How from the Composite point of View I can get it's View, in which this Composite is placed?

Comment: could you post a small code-snippet?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to get it from the Composite?

Comment: I want to close Shell, when for example View resizes. In Shell I have a list of values, which after clicking one of them fills up the TextBox on a View. To this View I want to attach a Listener on resize or anything else to close my Shell. Or simply, when a Text moves around Display let the Shell move as well. I don't know how to achieve that: the Shell acting like ComboBox. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call getParent() to get the parent control.  If the composite you are interested in is not the direct parent, consider passing the control you want into the constructor, and keeping track of it that way.